# How to format the description strings for attributes in steam web api?

Tags: xcode, steam-web-api

When I use this link to grab the item schema for TF2, (http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&language=en), under the attributes property, there's a list of every attribute in the game for TF2.

For example this is one such attribute:

```
{
            "name": "gesture speed increase",
            "defindex": 201,
            "attribute_class": "mult_gesture_time",
            "description_string": "+%s1% faster taunt speed on wearer",
            "description_format": "value_is_percentage",
            "effect_type": "positive",
            "hidden": false,
            "stored_as_integer": false
},
```

Under the `"description_string"` property you can see that the string uses a format specifier, but how do implement this in xcode. %s1 in xcode isn't the correct format specifier for strings, so how do I change it?

**EDIT:** What I'm trying to do it basically use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%s1% faster taunt speed on wearer", @"25"]`. The problem is that when I NSLog this statement, the number doesn't show up and instead some weird symbols do. I want to have the statement "+25% faster taunt speed on wearer", so how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best approach is to drop `stringWithFormat:` else you will have to escape characters like `%`.

You could do either of the following:

**Single occurrence of %s1**
If you are guaranteed that `%s1` will only occur once in the `description_string` you could simply use:

```
NSString *description = @"+%s1% faster taunt speed on wearer";
description = [description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%s1" withString:@"25"];
```

**Multiple occurrence of %s1**

```
NSString *description = @"+%s1% faster taunt speed on wearer and +%s1 XP";
NSArray *values = @[@"25", @"1000"];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, description.length);
NSUInteger index = 0;
while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    range = [description rangeOfString:@"%s1" options:0 range:range];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *value = values[index];
        description = [description stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:value];
        range = NSMakeRange(range.location + value.length, description.length - (range.location + value.length));
    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped! I will try it out and give some feedback.